# Find the number of trees on the vertex set V = {1, 2, ..., 8} in which all vertices have degree 1 or 4.

Tags: combinatorics, trees

I am unclear how to figure this out. 
I understand that if there were 6 vertices of deg = 1 and 2 vertices of deg = 4 then I can simply check if the degrees all add up to 2n-2 and use a specific thm:
(n-2)!/[(deg_1 - 1)!*...*(deg_n - 1)!] 
but that same thm does not seem to apply in this case because I do not have the specific degrees for each vertex. Would I use Cayley's thm to solve this where we have n^(n-2) trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

- How many edges does a tree on $8$ vertices have?
- What is the sum of the degrees of its vertices?

Use the answers to those two questions to show that there is a unique unlabelled tree that satisfies these conditions. Then count the inequivalent ways to label the vertices of that tree with the integers $1,\ldots,8$. (This last step is a fairly simple counting problem.)

Comment: So there are 7 edges on a tree with 8 vertices and the sum of the degrees should be 14. I could figure that part out and the only unique tree that could be possible out of this is one in which you have 2 vertices of deg 4 and 6 vertices of deg 1. From here am I just counting this arbitrarily ? as in I have to randomly choose which 2 vertices have deg = 4 so I have something like 8 choose 2 choices, which is 28 then I utilize the thm to find that for a fixed deg_1 to deg_8 there are 20 such trees so the total would be 20*28? just trying to make sure that is correct.

Comment: @aznmaniac42536: Yes, that’s right. There are $\binom82$ ways to label the non-leaves, and then there are $\binom63$ ways to choose labels for the leaves attached to the non-leaf with the smaller label, say. That completely determines the labelling, so you have $\binom82\binom63=28\cdot20=560$ labelled trees.

Comment: @aznmaniac42536: You’re very welcome!