# How many trees are there on $10$ vertices where two of them have degree $4$, one has degree $3$, and each of the other vertices have degree $1$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many trees are there on $10$ vertices where vertices $1$ and $2$ have degree $4$, $3$ has degree $3$, and each of the other vertices have degree $1$?

So far, I am able to determine that vertices $4, 5, 6,7, 8, 9$ and $10$ are leaves. My intuition also tells me this problem involves inclusion/exclusion somehow, but I can't quite figure out what values to calculate.

Comment: Hint: leaf nodes in a tree cannot connect to other leaf nodes, unless the total number of nodes is $2.$

Comment: I get: $$2\binom7{3,2,2}+\binom7{3,3,1}$$

Comment: Here are excellent references to solve your problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049175/find-the-number-of-trees-on-the-vertex-set-v-1-2-8-in-which-all-verti, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557218/how-many-trees-are-there-on-7-vertices-where-vertices-2-and-3-have-degree-3-5, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2644294/how-many-trees-on-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-have-a-vertex-of-degree-2, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080589/find-the-number-of-trees-on-2m-given-vertices-in-which-all-vertices-have-degre

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you only care about the trees up to graph isomorphism. In other words, I'm assuming that renumbering the vertices without changing the diagram doesn't count as a new tree. With that assumption, the vertex numbers aren't important, so we may as well assume $\deg(v_1) = 4, \deg(v_2) = 4, \deg(v_3) = 3$.

A tree with 10 vertices has 9 edges, so the sum of all vertex degrees will be $2 \cdot 9 = 18$. Vertices 1, 2, 3 have degree sum $4+4+3=11$ already, so the other 7 vertices must each have degree 1.

Two leaf nodes can't connect to each other, since then they wouldn't be able to connect anywhere else and your tree would end up disconnected. So $v_1, v_2, v_3$ must connect to each other in some way, and then the other leaves must get stuck onto the first three. To make $v_1, v_2, v_3$ connected we need exactly two edges among those three: 1 edge isn't enough to connect them, and 3 edges would make a cycle which is not allowed in trees.

The only options are:

1. Edges from $v_1$ to $v_2$ and from $v_2$ to $v_3$: Then the only option is to finish the tree by connecting 3 more leaves to $v_1$, 2 more leaves to $v_2$, and 2 more leaves to $v_3$.
2. Edges from $v_1$ to $v_2$ and from $v_1$ to $v_3$: Then you must finish the tree by connecting 2 more leaves to $v_1$, 3 more leaves to $v_2$, and 2 more leaves to $v_3$.
3. Edges from $v_1$ to $v_3$ and from $v_2$ to $v_3$: Then you must finish the tree by connecting 3 more leaves to $v_1$, 3 more leaves to $v_2$, and 1 more leaf to $v_3$.

Options (1) and (2) are actually the same, under the renaming $v_1 \leftrightarrow v_2$. Options (1) and (3) are different: in (1) the degree-4 vertices are adjacent, but in (3) they aren't. So in conclusion, there are $\color{blue}{2}$ possible trees up to graph isomorphism.

(Thanks to @VTand for pointing out a mistake in an earlier version of this answer.)

Comment: I think the graphs produced from options 1 and 2 will be isomorphic?

Comment: Yep, you got me. Thanks! I'll edit.